# QtCreator Boost Error: undefined reference to `_imp__WSACleanup@0'

Tags: qt, boost

I am using boost 1.57.0 and QT Creator 5.3 with MinGW 32Bit Compiler and I'm using WIndows8.1. I tried to link the Boost Libraries to my project and since it didn't work I started a little Testprogramm but I got the same errors. I've already tried all tutorials I could find but they didnt't work.

I compiled boost with MinGW to boost_libraries folder.
So here is my .pro File:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Test
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
DEFINES += BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK  # for using dynamic libraries

#here is the part with my boost libraries
DEPENDPATH += C:/boost_libraries/include/boost-1_57
INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost_libraries/include/boost-1_57
LIBS += -L "C:/boost_libraries/lib/" -lboost_thread-mgw48-mt-1_57

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

So here comes my Test Class:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And these are the Errors that I get trying to build it in Release and Debug mode:

```
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Test\main.cpp:-1: Fehler: undefined reference to `_imp__WSACleanup@0'
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Test\main.cpp:-1: Fehler: undefined reference to `_imp__WSAStartup@8'
:-1: Fehler: release/main.o: bad reloc address 0x3f in section `.text$_ZN5boost4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7startupERNS2_4dataEhh[__ZN5boost4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7startupERNS2_4dataEhh]'
collect2.exe:-1: Fehler: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

Hi. now I changed my code a little bit and my .pro file looks like this now:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Test
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
DEFINES += BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK  # for using dynamic libraries

DEPENDPATH += C:/boost_libraries/include/boost-1_57
INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost_libraries/include/boost-1_57

LIBS += -LC:/boost_libraries/lib/  \
           -lboost_thread-mgw48-mt-1_57 \
           -lboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_57 \
           -lboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-1_57

LIBS += -lws2_32

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Now I get this Errors:

```
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Test\main.cpp:-1: Fehler: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Test\mainwindow.cpp:-1: Fehler: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
moc_mainwindow.cpp:-1: Fehler: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
collect2.exe:-1: Fehler: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Did I make any mistakes linking lboost_system? I also tried out every library in a seperate line.

Comment: the WSA lib isn't included for the linker according to msdn it's Ws2_32.lib that you need to add to LIBS; though normally boost's headers self include them

Comment: Hi I can't find a Ws2_32.lib in my boost directory. Where can I get it from?

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32; it's a windows library and just doing `LIBS += -lWs2_32.lib` should work

Comment: Is it still unresolved?

Comment: Do you have `boost_system-mgw48-mt-1_57.dll` available in `C:/boost_libraries/lib/`?

Comment: The exact filename is: libboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_57.a I have all the .a files in C:/boost_libraries/lib and all the header files in C:/boost_libraries/include/boost-1_57